# Can a GRPC response be only bytes

Tags: grpc

I want to create a gRPC endpoint for downloading a file. It needs to work with `curl`.

```
message GetArtifactRequest {
  string namespace = 1;
}

message GetArtifactResponse {
  bytes content = 1;
}

service EventService {
  rpc GetArtifact(GetArtifactRequest) returns (GetArtifactResponse) {
    option (google.api.http) = {
      get : "/api/v1/artifacts/{namespace}"
    };
  }
}
```

How can I have it so that the response body in just `bytes`? Is that even possible.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, the closest thing is what your are doing in your example. gRPC is not really made for this kind of work, it is more suitable for structured data. I would recommend you have a HTTP server for serving you file and a gRPC one for structured data.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to achieve.